# how to related a weakly convergent random variable with its k-th moment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be independent random sequence with zero mean and unit variance.
>   Suppose $$S_n:=\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{X_m}{\sqrt{n}} \Rightarrow X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$ holds. (Here "$\Rightarrow$" means weakly convergence); Is it true that for given $k>0$, its kth moment
>   $$
> E[S_n^k] \rightarrow E[X^k] ?
> $$

[Approach 1]
This seems very related to the Central Limit Theorem flavor. I first try to using the definition $S_n \Rightarrow X$, then I can say for any bounded and continuous function $g$, I have
$$E[g(S_n)] \to E[g(X)]$$
but if I pick $g(x):=x^k$ which is NOT bounded...

[Approach 2] 
On the other hand, I also try another approach like this:

I exploit the fact that "if $S_n \Rightarrow X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then the characteristic function $\phi_{S_n}(t) \rightarrow \phi_X(t)$ for all $t$". So if I observe 
$$\begin{array}{l}
{\phi _{{S_n}}}\left( t \right) = E\left[ {{e^{it{S_n}}}} \right] \to E\left[ {{e^{itX}}} \right] = {\phi _X}\left( t \right)\\
 \Rightarrow {\phi _{{S_n}^k}}\left( t \right) = E\left[ {{e^{ikt{S_n}}}} \right] \to E\left[ {{e^{iktX}}} \right] = {\phi _{{X^k}}}\left( t \right)
\end{array}$$
Hence, I get for all $t$
$$E\left[ {{e^{ikt{S_n}}}} \right] \to E\left[ {{e^{iktX}}} \right]$$
but I still stuck to conclude further to get the following desired result
$$
E[S_n^k] \rightarrow E[X^k] ?
$$

Comment: This result holds if the family $\{S_n^k\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian, Thanks for reply, indeed I never learned the concept about uniformly integrable, could you say more words about this point ?

Comment: Whenever you have convergence in distribution of real random variables, you can switch probability spaces and make it almost sure convergence. This is called the Skorokhod representation theorem. Your question is then whether or not convergence a.s. implies convergence of integrals, which is not true in general. A necessary and sufficient condition for $L^k$ convergence (which implies what you want) is uniform integrability. This is slightly stronger than just having convergence of the expectations though.